# Sharepoint 2013 Sharing Documents in a library to different people

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, permissions, library

I have a page that shows a library.  The library has folders with documents in them.  I want to give access to the folders in the library to different people and have the people see only the folders I give them access to see.  Is that possible?

I've tried to stop inheriting from the parent on the page and on the library.  Then I have a group of owners and a separate group of restricted users.  I've shared one folder with each person in group of restricted users, but they can see the entire list of folders.  Not what I want. I want them to only see the folder I shared with them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set unique permission for each folder. In short, if you do not want folder B be accessed by group A, do not give group A permission for folder B.

For example, give restricted users permission only to folder A, you need to remove their permission for folder B or C if you do not want them see other folders.

Comment: Thanks.  We decided that the original site may have become "contaminated" with all the different things we did, so we created a new site.  Using stop inheriting permissions was our focus and it worked the way we wanted, and expected, on the new site.

Comment: If you think my suggestion is helpful, you could accept it as an answer.